# Date Entry - Advanced Filter

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please help me?

I have a spreadsheet which I am using Advanced Filter in VBA.
The cell "M5" is Date From and "N5" is Date To.
The idea is the user type "date from" and "date to" and get the data filtered.

I am using the code below, but it is not working. The data is not being filtered at all or partially filtered. Could anyone pls help me ?

```
Sub TableFilt()

Dim ToDate, FrDate        As Date

'Improve the performance of the macro
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    .DisplayAlerts = FALSE
End With

With Sheet6
    LastRow = .Range("E99999").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'If .Range("M5").Value = "From Date" Then FrDate = "1/1/2015" Else: FrDate = .Range("M5").Value                            
    'If .Range("N5").Value = "To Date" Then ToDate = "31/12/2030" Else: ToDate = Range("N5").Value                              
    
   .Range("E6:AU" & LastRow).Select
    
    Selection.AutoFilter
    With .Range("E6:AU" & LastRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">=" & FrDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & ToDate        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the Ifs supposed to be commented out? You aren't setting `ToDate` and `FrDate` to anything like this. It's also missing an `End with`

Comment: I just forgot to remove the comments @ChristoferWeber..Thanks for asking

Answer (score 0):

Made som changes, worked for me:

```
Sub TableFilt()

Dim ToDate As Date, FrDate As Date

With Sheet6
    LastRow = .Range("E99999").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If .Range("M5").Value = "From Date" Then FrDate = "1/1/2015" Else: FrDate = .Range("M5").Value
    If .Range("N5").Value = "To Date" Then ToDate = "31/12/2030" Else: ToDate = .Range("N5").Value

    With .Range("E6:AU" & LastRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">=" & FrDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & ToDate
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

1. AFAIK `Dim ToDate, FrDate        As Date` will only dim `FrDate` as a `date`, and leave `ToDate` as a `variant`. Should still work, but just as a note.
2. I don't see the point in disabling `ScreenUpdating`or `DisplayAlerts` when using AutoFilter, so that's removed. Shouldn't be more than one change anyway.
3. The two `If`s are needed, so we can't have those as comments. Also a missing dot in one of the ranges.
4. I don't see a point in selecting anything, so that's removed. The area is defined in the next row anyway.
5. A missing `End With` to complete the Sub.

Answer (score 0):

Date values are not text, but need formatting as string expressions for the criteria, so try this:

```vb
Sub TableFilt()

    Dim ToDate  As Date
    Dim FrDate  As Date

    ' Improve the performance of the macro
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = FALSE
        .DisplayAlerts = FALSE
    End With

    With Sheet6
        LastRow = .Range("E99999").End(xlUp).Row
        
        If .Range("M5").Value = "From Date" Then FrDate = #1/1/2015# Else: FrDate = .Range("M5").Value                            
        If .Range("N5").Value = "To Date" Then ToDate = #12/31/2030# Else: ToDate = .Range("N5").Value                              
        
        .Range("E6:AU" & LastRow).Select
        
        Selection.AutoFilter
        With .Range("E6:AU" & LastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">= #" & Format(FrDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<= #" & Format(ToDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.Your code helped me to figured it out. @Gustav

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered if you feel so.